# What can cause the JPEG image corruption, created with Imagick in PHP?

Tags: php, jpeg, imagick

Recently I've started having some troubles with PHP generated images. Look at this image: http://video.advisor.travel/960x545px-video_60.jpg .

As you can see this image is corrupted. The image is generated with the Imagick module by re-sizing the source image (islands and ocean in this case) and combining it with "Play" icon. Then the image is saved to disk with INTERLACE_PLANE option (simplified):

```
$this->image = new Imagick ();
$this->image->readImage($origFileName);
$this->image->resizeImage($width, $height, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, $this->blur);
$this->image->contrastImage(1);
$this->image->sharpenImage(0.8, 0.5);

$centered_left = $this->width / 2 - self::ICON_WIDTH / 2;
$centered_top = $this->height / 2 - self::ICON_WIDTH / 2;
$play_icon = new Imagick ();
$this->image->readImage($play_icon);

// Combine image and play icon
$this->image->compositeImage($play_icon, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $centered_left, $centered_top, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);

// Remove meta-data
$this->image->stripimage();

// Compress
$this->image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$this->image->setInterlaceScheme(Imagick::INTERLACE_PLANE);
$this->image->setImageCompressionQuality(90);

// Write to disk
$this->image->writeImage($destFileName);
```

I cannot tell what's going on as the majority of images works good and even slight change for the image sizes (for example, http://video.advisor.travel/960x544px-video_60.jpg , just 1 pixel less) will (or will not :)) be alright.

System runs in Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.5.20, imagick module version 3.1.2, ImageMagick version 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16.

Any ideas why that can happen or how can I detect that the image was corrupted in-code will be most appreciated!

Comment: What is `$this->blur`? And did you try to use another filter?

Comment: There is a very high chance this is a bug in one of the libraries that Imagick relies on. I suggest trying a newer version of Ubuntu in a VM and seeing if the newer versions of ImageMagick have this issue. I think the image may just be cut-off, with not all the data generated, when the image is saved.

Comment: @puelo $this->blur is just a constant = 0.85

Comment: @Danack Yes, I think that it is an issue with library too. Bad thing is that I cannot reliably reproduce it even on my current setup but I'll dig further, thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend just generating a huge number of images on your local machine, and then scanning through them quickly. If you can't replicate it with the same libraries locally, then there is a real chance that you have a bad memory module on your server.